# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, express

I have an error whenever I try to test my endpoint for the database it says "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR"

so this is my model for mysql database:

```
let query = `UPDATE tbl_branch_info 
            SET 
            ${whats === undefined ? `` : `whats=${whats},`}
            ${twitter === undefined ? `` : `twitter='${twitter}',`}
            ${facebook === undefined ? `` : `facebook='${facebook}',`}
            ${snapchat === undefined ? `` : `snapchat='${snapchat}',`}
            ${instagram === undefined ? `` : `instagram='${instagram}',`}
            ${phone === undefined ? `` : `telephone=${phone},`}
            ${address === undefined ? `` : `address='${address}',`}
            ${email === undefined ? `` : `email='${email}',`}
            ${city_id === undefined ? `` : `city_id=${city_id},`}
            ${category_id === undefined ? `` : `category_id=${category_id},`}
            ${subCategoryId === undefined ? `` : `sub_cat_id=${subCategoryId},`}
            ${lon === undefined ? `` : `lon=${lon},`}
            ${lat === undefined ? `` : `lat=${lat}`}     
            WHERE branch_id = ${branch_id}`;
```

it gives me this error :

[error message from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k09eh.jpg)

but then if I change the last line before the the branch_id which is the lat to this

```
lat='${lat}'
```

it will pass data just fine, so what could be the problem here ?

Comment: Show `query` value which causes this error message.

Comment: @Akina i just gave some values not all to test if this method will work, i gave branch_id, address and facebook only, but like i said if I change the lat only it will work normally, and if i delete it making the lon only it will also give an error so i think something is wrong with the syntax or something is missing but i can't identify it

Comment: @Akina i uploaded an image to the post of the response from postman

Comment: You have an extra comma `,` before `where` statement. Use an ORM to build queries, your way is not safe. It is complex too, if you have some values available while others are null.

Comment: @Shaharyar where is the comma ? the last comma I have is after the "lon"?
yeah i'm just testing but i wanna know where the problem is

Comment: *where is the comma ?* After `address` assigning.

Comment: If you don't have `lat` value, then each last value will end on comma `,`. Suppose you have only `facebook` and `address` values, now your code will add a comma after `address` and then append the `where` clause. You can see `sql` field in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the help im trying to process comments right now, appreciate it

Comment: @Shaharyar Oh okay i think i started to understand what you mean, because earlier i was trying to count comma's and i didnt find any extra commas, Thanks a lot for the explanation, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let query = `UPDATE tbl_branch_info 
            SET 
            ${whats === undefined ? `` : `whats=${whats},`}
            ${twitter === undefined ? `` : `twitter='${twitter}',`}
            ${facebook === undefined ? `` : `facebook='${facebook}',`}
            ${snapchat === undefined ? `` : `snapchat='${snapchat}',`}
            ${instagram === undefined ? `` : `instagram='${instagram}',`}
            ${phone === undefined ? `` : `telephone=${phone},`}
            ${address === undefined ? `` : `address='${address}',`}
            ${email === undefined ? `` : `email='${email}',`}
            ${city_id === undefined ? `` : `city_id=${city_id},`}
            ${category_id === undefined ? `` : `category_id=${category_id},`}
            ${subCategoryId === undefined ? `` : `sub_cat_id=${subCategoryId},`}
            ${lon === undefined ? `` : `lon=${lon},`}
            ${lat === undefined ? `` : `lat=${lat},`}    
            ${`branch_id = ${branch_id}`} 
            WHERE branch_id = ${branch_id}`;
```